# WP Background Processing - Class 'WP_Async_Request' not found

Tags: wordpress, background, processing

I need to do some background processing on WordPress, I found this library:
https://github.com/deliciousbrains/wp-background-processing

I tried using the example plugin found here:
https://github.com/A5hleyRich/wp-background-processing-example

And every time I tried to activate the plugin The website crash and on PHP log show

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Async_Request' not found in....

Any help please, I really need this.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

WP_Async_Request class is not a part of WordPress.
You should have been installed woocommerce or install WP_Async_Request class and all this library directly.